# What are the best ways to typeset a table with large texts in LateX?

Tags: tables, width

I am trying to put a Table with 3 rows and two columns but the second column contain a discription with a couple of sentences. How can I write the table command to put the table accordingly to the Latex File?
Here an example of the table that I would like to put:

```latex
\begin{table}[h]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,skip=0pt}
    \caption{Arten der Reichweite von RFID-Systemen \cite{Internetquelle2}}
    \scriptsize 
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
            \toprule[1pt]
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text . Text Text ext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Textext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\\     
            \midrule
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\ 
            \midrule
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\
            \bottomrule[1pt]
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

This is the Output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHYAM.png

Thanks a lot in Advance for the help!

Comment: Never use \resizebox for a table – it leads to inconsistent font sizes. The simplest in this case would be to load `tabularx` and use this code `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}… \end{tabularx}`.

Comment: None. For large texts,it  is always better another formats, as description lists, sections, etc. Said that, for ***short*** texts, learn about tabular `p` columns (run `texdoc array,` page two),  tabularx (`texdoc tabularx`) and  `tabulary` (yes, `texdoc tabulary`)

Comment: @Bernard I replaces begin{tabular} with begin{tabularx} as you wrote it. I get the following error:
Package caption Error: \caption outside float. \end{tabularx}


\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|}
 \captionsetup{justification=centering,skip=0pt}
 \caption{Arten der Reichweite von RFID-Systemen \cite{Internetquelle2}}
% \scriptsize 
% \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%  \begin{tabularx}{@{}|l|X|@{}}
 \textbf{TEXT} & TEXT //
 \textbf{TEXT} & TEXT //
 \textbf{TEXT} & TEXT //
 \end{tabularx}%

Comment: Yes, of course. `\caption` is for floats (table, figure, algorithm, &c.). If for some reason, you don't want a  `table` environment around `tabularx`, you can  load the `caption` package, and use `\caption[table]{Some caption}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general comment up front: You've provided a *perfect* minimum working example! Many thanks.

Even though opinions may differ as to which approach is *best* for typesetting the table at hand, there has got to be near-unanimity as to which approach is *worst*: the approach that doesn't allow line-breaking in cells and forces the width of the resulting catastrophe of a table not to exceed `\textwidth` (the width of the text block) via a `\resizeblock` instruction. As the screenshot below aptly demonstrates, the result is a typographic abomination.

For the table at hand, it's (hopefully) obvious that any good approach *must* start by allowing automatic line breaking in the second column. This may be achieved by using the `p` column type instead of the `l` column type. I recommend making LaTeX handle the chore of determining the width of the `p` column by employing the `tabularx` package, setting the overall width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, and employing an `X` column (which is nothing but a `p` column for which LaTeX performs the width calculation on the fly) for the second column.

In the screenshot, I contrast the results of the sngle-worst approach with the `tabularx` approach. I suppose it's not much of a contest, is it?

Note that, for the second table, I've also omitted all vertical and horizontal rules and automated the **bold-facing** of the contents of the first column.

In keeping with the theme that it's difficult to determine which particular approach is *best* for typesetting the material at hand, I provide an additional solution, *viz.*, an approach that employs a `description` list environment. For the material at hand, I beleve it's hard to tell whether or not the `description` approach is better or worse than the `tabularx` approach. For sure, though, both are infinitely better than the first approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \resizebox macro
\usepackage{caption}  % for \captionsetup macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx environment and X column type
\captionsetup{justification=centering,skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Version with \texttt{\string\scriptsize} \emph{and} \texttt{\string\resizebox} macros. Ouch!}
    \scriptsize 
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
            \toprule[1pt]
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text . Text Text ext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Textext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\\     
            \midrule
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\ 
            \midrule
            \textbf{Text Text } & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\
            \bottomrule[1pt]
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Version with \texttt{tabularx} environment}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l X @{}}
    Text Text  
    & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\\     
    \addlinespace
    Text Text
    & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\ 
    \addlinespace
    Text Text
    & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Version with \texttt{description} environment}
\begin{description}[topsep=0pt]
\item[Text Text] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text
\item[Text Text] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\item[Text Text] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\end{description}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Now I am trying to put a much bigger table with 5 columns and 12 rules. But it is not working. I asked a separate question for this matter. In case you have a solution for the issue too, I would be very thankful :)
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609009/how-can-i-use-tabularx-for-tables-with-many-columns-properly

Comment: @ramles - Please see the answer I provided for your follow-up query.

Comment: An off-topic comment: The latest (fifth) upvote on this answer raised my rep point count on this site to just over 400,000. Many thanks!! TeX.SE is a great community, and after more than ten years of active participation, I continue to be a very happy member and contributor.